# How to calculate the areas of cells in an image with Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

Below is an image of cells (adapted from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369526618300311), Figure 1):

[image]

where the scale bar is $20 \mu m$. Is there any way to calculate the areas of cells with Mathematica?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at posts like this [Area of a image region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100725/41569)?

Comment: As @creidhne already mentioned, please provide some of your code. Otherwise, the key functions would be ``ComponentMeasurements`` and ``MorphologicalComponents``. However, some image preprocessing will be needed, together with the appropriate calibration with the scale bar. Simple, but quite inaccurate example: ``ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@Erosion[Dilation[EdgeDetect[img, 1.5, .05], 1.6], 1.4], "Area"]``.

Comment: A student, I see you edited this post recently; if you find that an answer has answered your question, it is helpful to mark it as “accepted” by turning the checkmark green by clicking on it—it is located under the +/-1 vote buttons. It looks like this is solved, from my perspective, as the answer from @Domen would work well if the image was preprocessed to remove the `(b)` marking from the image.

Comment: I have implemented the idea of @GeorgeVarnavides and also provided the results for figure (a).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Import all images

```
figA = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM8fK.jpg"];
figB = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WFEF.jpg"];
figBSmall = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjnRy.png"];
```

### Select and crop the image

```
imgOrig = figBSmall;
img = ImageCrop[imgOrig];
```

### Find the white scale bar

We look for the scale bar in the bottom-right part of the image. Only one morphological component should be found.

```
imgLowerThird = 
  ImageTake[
   img, -ImageDimensions[img][[2]]/3, -ImageDimensions[img][[1]]/3];
imgBW = Dilation[Erosion[Binarize[imgLowerThird, .9], 1], 1];
scaleBar = MorphologicalComponents[DeleteBorderComponents@imgBW];
Max[scaleBar]
(* 1 *)

scaleBar // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Determine scale bar height and calculate area factor

```
scaleBarRealHeight = Quantity[20, "Micrometers"];

scaleBarHeight = #[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]] &@(1 /. 
     ComponentMeasurements[scaleBar, "BoundingBox"])
(* 25. *)

areaFactor = scaleBarRealHeight^2/scaleBarHeight^2
(* Quantity[0.64, ("Micrometers")^2] *)
```

### Preprocess image

First, we remove the image label (b) and the scalebar, as proposed by @GeorgeVarnavides in the comment.

```
maxComponentSize = 15;
inpaintDilation = 1;

imgInpaint = 
 Inpaint[img, 
  Dilation[DeleteBorderComponents[
    DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, 0.9], maxComponentSize]], 
   inpaintDilation]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since cell borders are much darker than the interior, we convert the image to HSL color space and take the lightness channel. Furthermore, we crop the image and make a thin border so that the boundary cells are well separated. Small specks are removed by `DeleteSmallComponents` (once for the black and once for the white specks).

In this step, manual adjustment of four parameters can be made so that the output image `edgesWithBorder` has well-defined and connected cell boundaries without any black or white specks.

```
contrastAdj = 1;
threshold = .95;
cropWidth = 2;
specksSize = 50;

imgAdj = ImageAdjust[imgInpaint, contrastAdj];
imgB = ColorSeparate[ColorConvert[imgAdj, "HSB"]][[3]];
imgBinarized = Binarize[imgB, threshold];
edges = ColorNegate@
   DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@imgBinarized, specksSize, 
    CornerNeighbors -> False];
edges = DeleteSmallComponents[edges, specksSize, 
   CornerNeighbors -> False];
edgesCropped = 
  ImageTake[edges, {cropWidth, -cropWidth}, {cropWidth, -cropWidth}];
edgesWithBorder = ImagePad[edgesCropped, 1];
{imgB, edgesWithBorder} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Find cells

```
cells = MorphologicalComponents[edgesWithBorder, 
   CornerNeighbors -> False];
cells // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Calculate cell centroid and area

```
centroid = ComponentMeasurements[cells, {"Centroid"}];
centroidLoc = centroid[[All, 2, 1]];
area = ComponentMeasurements[cells, {"Area"}];
```

### Output the results

```
HighlightImage[#, Table[ImageMarker[centroidLoc[[i]],
      Graphics[Style[Text@ToString@i, White, Bold]]], {i, 1, 
      Length@centroidLoc}]
    ] & /@ {img, 
   Colorize[cells, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]} // GraphicsRow
Grid[Transpose@(PadRight[#, 10, ""] & /@ 
    Partition[
     Table[Row[{ToString@i, ": ", 
        Round[areaFactor*First[i /. area]]}], {i, 1, 
       Length@centroid}], UpTo[10]]), Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: Results (b)]

### Figure (a)

```
inpaintDilation = 6;
threshold = .94;
cropWidth = 8;
specksSize = 300;
```

[image: Results (a)]

### Evaluation

Most of the cells seem to be correctly recognized and measured. However, expect the results to have an error of about $5 \%$ for the middle cells (and significantly more for the cells on the edge of the figure). This can be seen by varying the preprocessing parameters or using high-resolution image (`figB` vs. `figBSmall`). Also note that the removal of image label and scalebar with `InPaint` produces artificial cell boundaries, which means the areas of surrounding cells have greater error.

Comment: @Astudent, I have made some updates to make the code more robust. The problem was with figure 1 (a) was finding the scale bar, so now it takes only the bottom right part. Furthermore, I have explicitly specified two parameters that can be manually varied. Of course, in the preprocessing stage, you can apply some additional adjustments that will enhance cell boundaries.

Comment: Re: removing the scale-bar/label while preserving cell boundaries, perhaps `Inpaint` can help. E.g. pre-processing with something like this seems to work well `Inpaint[imageA, 
 Dilation[DeleteBorderComponents[
   DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[imageA, 0.9], 250]], 5]]` (where `imageA` is a 1048x962 image of Figure 1a from the attached paper)