# How to give a scale bar in microscopy image?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image, scaling

I have a *Differential interference contrast* microscopy ([DIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_interference_contrast_microscopy)) image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfEZx.png"]
```

[image: Microscopy Image]

I have made some image adjustment using, [`ImageTrim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTrim.html), [`ImageResize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html), and      [`ImageAdjust`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html)

```
ImageTrim[
 ImageResize[
  ImageAdjust[img, {0.7, 0.75, 0.9}], {250, 266}], {{.08, .30}, {0.55, 
   0.75}}, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

and get,

[image: Scaled and trimmed image]

This clearly has altered the image scaling.

**How can one overlay a scale bar with proper length?**

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! What do you mean by "give the scale bar"? Do you mean "get the scale bar"? Also, have you seen [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253626/75628)?

Comment: Actually, as the size of the micrograph already modified, I need to mention the scale bar with the modified length which maintain the same aspect ratio with the particle size

Comment: I provided an answer to the question, but I would appreciate if somebody could figure out how to extract the `pixelsPerMeter` information directly from the image using *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfEZx.png", "PNG"];
```

From the metadata (extracted from [here](https://www.metadata2go.com/result#j=7efcfb86-4901-4649-82c4-b00239e23b89)) we can get the scaling of the picture.

```
pixelsPerMeter = {7710892, 7710892}
```

(I didn't mange to get the metadata from *Mathematica*)

We can check by overlaying a 10 x 1 micrometers bar on the original scale bar

```
Graphics[
  {
     img
     , Red
     , Rectangle @@ {#, # + N[pixelsPerMeter {10, 1} 10^-6]} &[{1797, 1369}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Now you are scaling with [`ImageResize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html) from `{1920, 1440}` to `{250, 266}`, distorting the image.

```
scaledImg = 
 ImageTrim[
  ImageResize[
   ImageAdjust[img, {0.7, 0.75, 0.9}], {250, 
    266}], {{.08, .30}, {0.55, 0.75}}
 , DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

The new scale is

```
newscale = pixelsPerMeter*{250, 266}/ImageDimensions[img]
```

[image]

and we can place a scale "Square" of 10x10 micrometers

```
With[
 {
  lbcorner = {10, 10}, (* In pixels *)
  boxsize = newscale *{10, 10} *Power[10, -6](* In pixels *)
  },
 Graphics[{
   scaledImg
   , Red
   , Rectangle @@ Accumulate[{lbcorner, boxsize}]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Please notice the undesirable distortion on the "square" you have introduced by forcing a change in the aspect ratio.